# Using Dominated Convergence Theorem with partial derivatives

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

I am so confused on how to do this, my professor made it sound simple and I'm sure it is, but I cannot figure this out:

Let $g\in \mathcal{C}^1(\mathbb{R}^{N+1})$ and define $f(x)=\int_a^b g(x,y)dy$ for $x\in\mathbb{R}^N$. Use the Dominated Convergence Theorem to show that for every $j=1,..., N$ we have

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}f(x) =\int_a^b\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j} g(x,y)dy.$$

So, I know that

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}f(x) = \frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}\int_a^b g(x,y)dy$$
and then the DCT will let us swap the integral with the partial derivative, but how on earth do you use the DCT here?  [If $f_n\in L^1(\mathbb{R}^N)$ converges almost everywhere to a function $f$ and there exists $h\in L^1(\mathbb{R}^N)$ such that $|f_n|\leq h$ for all $n$, then $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R}^N)$ and $f_n\to f$ in norm.] Any help would be much appreciated, thank you! Also, we did not really use measure much in class, as weird as that sounds.

Comment: HINT:  $$\frac{\partial }{\partial x_j}\int_a^b g(x,y)\,dy=\lim_{h\to 0}\int_a^b \frac{g(x_1,\dots, x_j+h,\dots x_N,y)-g(x,y)}{h}\,dy$$Now, see if the DCT applies.

Comment: apart from @MarkViola s comment you should note that It's much easier to write this down if $N=1$, and the general case is just the same.

Comment: Sorry, I'm having a tough time seeing what the sequence of functions and what the dominating function are.

Comment: Fix $x$.  Apply the Mean Value Theorem to the difference quotient.  Exploit the continuity of $\frac{\partial g}{\partial x_j}$ to obtain a dominating function.  Set $h=1/n$ and let $n\to \infty$.  Does that help?

Comment: No, I'm completely lost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We’re going to use the mean value theorem construct a dominating function over a sequence of functions which converges to $\partial_xf$.

First, satisfy yourself that $f_n(x,y)=n(f(x+\frac{1}{n},y)-f(x,y))$ converges to $\partial_x f$

Applying the mean value theorem, notice that for some $a\in(x,x+\frac{1}{n})$, $\partial_xf(a,y)=f_n(x,y)$. This implies that $|f_n(x)|\leq|\sup_x \partial_x f(x,y)|$

We can therefore choose the constant function $g(x,y)= |\sup_x \partial_x f(x,y)|$. This is integrable because constant functions are integrable over finite intervals

I’ll leave the details to you, but apply the dominated convergence theorem to show that $\lim_{n\to\infty} \int f_n(x,y)= \int \lim_{n\to\infty} f_n(x,y)$

Comment: I cannot see your $f_n$'s converge to $\partial_x f$ whatsoever. Could you elaborate? Other than that, everything else makes sense, though I would have to adapt it to $N>1$.

Comment: @Jeff consider $(f(x+h,y)-f(x,y))/h$, taking h to zero. That’s the partial of f with respect to x. Now replace h with 1/n, 1/n goes to 0 as n to infinity.

Comment: Should you have written $f_n(x,y)=\frac{1}{n}(f(x+\frac{1}{n},y)-f(x,y))$?

Comment: Sorry, ignore that